# mysql долго выполняет запросы

Tags: mysql

Поставил ubuntu 16.04, на неё сервак mysql. Похоже, что запросы все выполняются очень долго. При импорте дампа в консоли я успеваю прочитать почти каждый результат запроса, хотя не должен. Они должны очень быстро бежать

Comment: Как минимум, приведите тут ваши конфиги, ну и версию `mysql`

Comment: Вы бы как нибудь количественно это замерили, а не по ощущениям говорили. Может у вас консоль при выводе тормозит. посмотрите общую загрузку системы, с помощью `top`, например. Загрузку дисков `iostat`